# Which multi currency/token wallet exist for ETH, BTC and XMR?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I saw that Jaxx doesn't support Monero. Is there another multi token wallet, which supports all three mentioned currencies?

Answer (score 1):

Patients, hold on to your horses... I wish I could have my cake and eat it to.

Until Monero hard forks, occurring roughly semiannually, slow down or until very strong software interfaces exist few wallet vendors have the resources to adequately support Monero. Monero is pushing the envelope for privacy services and everything must be coded from the ground up unlike Bitcoin-based altcoins.

There has yet to be a dedicated production-ready mobile Monero wallet or Monero hardware-based wallet. [**Jaxx**](https://jaxx.io/) spun their wheels to support Monero until the Ring Confidential Transactions (CT) hard fork occurred. The [**X Wallet**](https://xwallet.tech/) currently appears to be the only viable moble Monero wallet in the pipeline, but is not a multicurrency wallet.  There was a very short period over a year ago the [**Exodus Wallet**](https://www.exodus.io/) supported a now fully deprecated version of Monero after a hardfork.

Similarly, there was a very short period were there was alpha code that supported Monero on a Trezor until Ring CT hit the streets. Monero support on a Ledger hardware wallet is in the pipeline.

However, BIP 32,39,44 technologies used by Jaxx (along with BIP 47) and other hardware wallets can be extended to support Monero, see this [**libbitcoin Monero example**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#10-monero-xmr-bip-3944-technology-examples). This leads to two working examples for how BIP 39 seed words can be deterministically mapped the 25 Electrum words used to reconstitute Monero wallets.

Comment: Monerujo is a fully functioning mobile wallet in the play store for Android right now.

Answer (score 1):

Ledger will likely be the first. They seem to have set up most of under-the-hood stuff, and now it's polishing, review and testing I suppose. Anyways, they're kind enough to give regular updates on Reddit as to how it's going - last of those can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/75w4s4/ledger_hardware_wallet_monero_integration_some/).

Coinomi may be the second one to add support. There's no ETA or progress updates. Back in July (2017) they [decided for "radio silence"](https://medium.com/@coinomi/monero-and-the-art-of-stfu-7f802947411e) due to pestering by some people on social networks.